# jQuery - autocomplete + append functions

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a page where I want to dynamically add more text fields and for this purpose I'm using the jQuery .append function. However, I also want to have those text fields being autocompleted by using yet another jQuery function. Here's what I have as JavaScript:

```
<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $("#addInputs").click(function() {
        $("#inputList").append("<input type='text' id='autocomplete' size='35' name='sales[]' /><br />");
    });
});
</script>
<script>
$(function ac() {
  var availableTags = [
    "ActionScript",
    "AppleScript",
    "Scheme"
  ];
  $( "#autocomplete" ).autocomplete({
    source: availableTags
  });
});
</script>
```

I have the following HTML:

```
    <div id='inputList'>
    <input type='text' id='autocomplete' size='35' name='sales[]' /><br />
    </div>
    <a id='addInputs' />Add Inputs</a>";
```

The autocomplete works for the text field that I already have displayed on the screen once the page loads. The "Add Inputs" also works and correctly appends more fields on the screeen.

The problem is that those newly added fields do not trigger the autocomplete function. Any ideas how this could be achieved?

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is that the code uses the same id for every appended element.  Ids must be unique.  Refactor the code so that it sets a class attribute on the elements appended to the DOM.  Then use the class as the selector when you call the `autocomplete` function.

**Javascript**

```
<script>

      var availableTags = [
        "ActionScript",
        "AppleScript",
        "Scheme"
      ];

      $( document ).ready(function() {
        $("#addInputs").click(function() {
          //Adding the class
          $("#inputList").append("<input type='text' class='autocomplete' size='35' name='sales[]' /><br />");

          //Selector using the class
          $( ".autocomplete" ).autocomplete({
            source: availableTags
          });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you!
I changed the ids to class now but I'm still not getting the autocomplete to trigger on the newly added fields.

Comment: @user2500469 See the update. The call to `autocomplete` should be in the click event handler.

Answer (score 1):

try this :

```
$(document).on("focus", "#autocomplete", function(e) {
    if ( !$(this).data("autocomplete") ) {
        $(this).autocomplete({            
            source: availableTags
        });
    }
});
```

on my site works. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Once you add a new input element you need to initialize the widget on them.

```
$(function () {

    function autocomplete(el){
        $( el ).autocomplete({
            source: availableTags
        });

    }

    var availableTags = [
        "ActionScript",
        "AppleScript",
        "Scheme"
    ];

    autocomplete($("#autocomplete"))

    $("#addInputs").click(function() {
        var el = $("<input type='text' size='35' name='sales[]' /><br />").appendTo("#inputList");
        autocomplete(el)
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In HTML ID attribute should contain unique value, but not CLASS attribute so instead of id use class (class = "autocomplete")

Comment: Thank you!
Unfortunately, the results are exactly the same using class instead of id.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem occurred because of the `.autocomplete` function is binded just once for the elements already in the DOM, my suggestion is using the `.live` or `.on` binding so later elements can be binded to:

```
$('#autocomplete').on("focus", function(e) {
    if ( !$(this).data("autocomplete") ) {
        $(this).autocomplete({            
            source: availableTags
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: My assumption was similar - the append adds new elements but since they are not part of the initial DOM the autocomplete doesn't trigger on them.
I tried using both .on and .live as you indicated above but no success so far.